# Manga where MC turns elderly female elf young again

Tags: story-identification, manga

I only remember some parts of it. In the later chapters the MC was living as a tenant at an elf's place in a village and she was an adventurer/magician back then. Prior to making her younger again (without her noticing) he saved the people of the village of a monster stampede and fought together with her against some goblins (?) that tried to "backdoor" the village. Other than that I remember him having 2 (or maybe only one and the other was another adventurer or something) female companions by that time that went ahead to warn the other people that were doing wood work outside of the village. I don't remember if it was an isekai, a reincarnation, or just a "kicked out of the party" manga. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you remember where you read it? Whether the protagonists were fair-skinned? Hair color? How many chapters?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Unfortunately I am not so sure anymore. I think the protagonist was the classic black hair, normal figure. And when I stopped or rather above mentioned chapter was around 25/30-ish I think (but could be completely wrong). If I remember correctly I read it on Manganato.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Yakutatazu Skill ni Jinsei wo Tsugikomi 25-nen, Imasara Saikyou no Boukentan](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/yakutatazu-skill-ni-jinsei-wo-tsugikomi-25-nen-imasara-saikyou-no-boukentan)*.

> A skill useless from the beginning, "Restoration". Regardless, in order to save a childhood friend who sacrificed her body to protect him, Touru spent twenty-five years developing the skill. Once completed, the skill could completely defy the world’s common sense. Touru, the girl, the naughty child they picked up in a back alley, and the old landlord lady join together as companions, setting out on an adventure to become heroes. A man who lived through the depths of despair decided to move forward and widen his horizons.

The transformation happens in chapter 12. Which is in the middle of a goblin stampede.

[image: Elf landlady as an old woman]

And then he uses his time magic and accidentally makes her younger again, which she doesn't notice until the next chapter.

[image: Younger looking elf]

Comment: Oh yes, that's the one I was looking for. Thanks!